# Aggregating data to count answers in R

Tags: r, variables, dataset, aggregation

I have a large data set in **R**, my question is related to 8 different variables in this data set, asking about peoples' networks. The variables all assign a code to different people, specifying the relationship to this person..

I would like to summarize the answer codes into two groups (friends=1, family=2) and then create a new variable that counts how many friends and family people list across the 8 variables.

I hope that is understandable and I would greatly appreciate your help.

That's how my data looks like:

```
 [117,]  id 106  201  202  102  103  452  452  501
 [118,]  id 106  201  202  302  301  451   NA   NA
 [119,]  id 201  202  106  102  105  601  602  602
 [120,]  id 106  201  202  406  301  302   NA   NA
```

I would like two variables that count the absoulute number of friends and family for each participants.

101-452 are family codes apart from 106 and 120

501-801 are friend codes, apart from 702

Comment: Please show few lines of your data and expected result

Comment: `colSums(df==401 | df==402)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bit more roundabout than what you want, but this solution is straightforward.  Since you didn't provide a `dput()` of your dataframe, I took the liberty of recreating the dataframe you posted:

```
    dF <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("id", 106, 201, 202, 102, 103, 452, 452, 501, 
                                        "id", 106, 201, 202, 302, 301, 451, NA, NA, 
                                        "id", 201, 202, 106, 102, 105, 601, 602, 602,  
                                        "id", 106, 201, 202, 406, 301, 302, NA, NA), 
                               ncol = 9, nrow = 4, byrow = T))
    names(dF) <- c("value", paste0("c", seq(1:8)))
```

I also had to adjust the class of each column in dF because of the `id` value:

```
    #Change each column to a numeric variable
    dF$c1 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c1))
    dF$c2 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c2))
    dF$c3 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c3))
    dF$c4 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c4))
    dF$c5 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c5))
    dF$c6 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c6))
    dF$c7 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c7))
    dF$c8 <- as.numeric(as.character(dF$c8))
```

Next, you have to create some way of telling `R` what is and isn't `family` and `friend`:

```
    #101-452 are family codes apart from 106 and 120
    #501-801 are friend codes, apart from 702
    fam <- as.numeric(c(101:105, 107:119, 121:452))
    fnd <- as.numeric(c(501:701, 703:801))
```

I wrote a function called `SumIn()` to determine if each value in each row of `dF` appears in `fam` or `fnd`:

```
    SumIn <- function(x){
      #Create a sum for each row of your dataframe where the column value is 
      # within the parameters you've given for both "family" and "friend"
      valFam <- sum(x %in% fam, na.rm = T)
      valFnd <- sum(x %in% fnd, na.rm = T)

    #Combine the two
      vals <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(valFam, valFnd)))

      return(vals)
    }
```

I created a new dataframe to make things easy, but you could easily apply this to your current dataframe:

```
    newDf <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 11, nrow = nrow(dF)))
    names(newDf) <- c("id", paste0("c", seq(1:8)), "sumFam", "sumFnd")  
    newDf$id <- "id"
```

Because you only want to apply to the numbers in the original dF, simply subset the dF to `apply()` to those colums.

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(dF)){
      newDf[i, 2:11] <- cbind(dF[i, 2:9], apply(dF[i, ], 1, SumIn))
    }

    > newDf
      id  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8 sumFam sumFnd
    1 id 106 201 202 102 103 452 452 501      6      1
    2 id 106 201 202 302 301 451  NA  NA      5      0
    3 id 201 202 106 102 105 601 602 602      4      3
    4 id 106 201 202 406 301 302  NA  NA      5      0
```

You should be able to eliminate the creating the `newDf` and apply it directly to your dataframe.  I just did it here as an example.

This may be a bit *hacky*, but it's straightforward and doesn't require a bunch of R knowledge.  I'm sure there are other methods by which to get the result you need.